# How to replace a node value using vbscript?

Tags: xml, vbscript, xmlnode

Take the following code:

```
' Set up the response for the request
Set nodeTier = CreateNode(rootResponse, "RequestResponse", "")
Set nodeTierSuccess = CreateNode(nodeTier, "SuccessCode", "1")
Set nodeTierSuccess = CreateNode(nodeTier, "Order", "")
```

How would I change the 'SuccessCode' value from '1' to '0'?

Comment: "Change the value" in what context?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to lookup the methods used in this demo code:

```
>> Set oX = CreateObject("msxml2.domdocument")
>> Set oX.documentElement = oX.createElement("a")
>> Set oS = oX.createElement("s")
>> oS.appendChild oX.createTextNode("0")
>> oX.documentElement.appendChild oS
>> WScript.Echo oX.xml
>> oS.text = "1"
>> WScript.Echo oX.xml
>>
<a><s>0</s></a>

<a><s>1</s></a>
```